# Is a two-handed solo piano score a kind of full score?

Tags: sheet-music, terminology

I'm working on a music categorization project, basically I have to classify what category should this sheet belongs to, but it only has two categories: *is full score* or *is not*.

As far as I know, full scores should have two lanes or more, and put a `{` on the left. But solo piano only needs one player to play. Should I put it in the full score category or not?

PS: Sorry for bad English, specifically in music theory.

Edit: This project is meant to categorize the sheets to make them easier to find by the public.

Comment: By the way, to get better answers, please edit to tell more about *why* you're doing this categorization. Is it a learning assignment? For your own interest? Are you building an app?

Comment: It depends on your definition of 'full score'.

Comment: I used to work in a shop selling sheet music, and in the music publishing industry, sheet music for piano solo is not a full score.  But as others have noted, you haven't given us enough information about your system of categorization or about the application of that system to know whether this is useful information to you.

Comment: _Is not [full score]_ can mean different things. Your categorization system is probably missing an upper category between _ensemble music_ and _solo music_. Then a solo piano score would go in _solo music_, and _ensemble music_ would contain _full score_ (the definition you provide is correct) and _part scores_, which would, typically, show only one of the instruments in the ensemble, and rarely, more than one, but not all of them.

Comment: @ComputerUser121212 you're right about the "ensemble music" aspect, but "part score" is not a standard term.  There are _parts,_ of course, as well as _study scores, condensed scores, miniature scores, vocal scores,_ and _choral scores,_ at least, as well as a notational technique called _short score,_ though I don't remember ever seeing a document calling itself a "short score."

Comment: This project is for my library, my boss just ask me to index the sheets to the system, and they use their own system to categorize, for now I can only choose between yes or no. I will ask my boss what will they do with them.

Comment: @TWTom Asking your boss makes sense since you need to know what system is applied in the library. The term "full" obvisously indicates that everything is there which would of course mean all parts. But with that definition also a piece for just one instrument could be called "full score" since there is nothing more to show. Normally I think you would only add the word "full" in front of the word "score" if there is more than one instrument. But often you would just use the word "score" also for a big orchestra without the term "full" even everything is shown. Thus: What does the boss want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, tricky to answer. I think the simplest answer is "no, you wouldn't use the phrase 'full score' for piano music." Generally, the word "score" is for what conductors use, showing the music for more than one instrument, in contrast to "parts," which show the music for only one instrument. What makes it a score doesn't really have to do with the layout or how the staves are printed; those are just conventions to make it easy to read.

Now, sometimes the word "score" is also used in a way that just means "printed music." And if piano is the only instrument, then in this sense I suppose it's "full." But it would be odd or even misleading to use a phrase that's usually used for orchestras for a solo piano piece instead. So I don't think I would pay much attention to this argument, especially for a simple assignment.

Another tricky situation is: in some small ensemble pieces, the piano part shows all the instruments. Like, a "piano trio" usually means a piano, a violin, and a cello. The violin and cello would usually read from parts that show only their music, but the piano would often read from something that shows all three. This would be the trickiest situation, because in this case the pianist's copy *is* the fullest score there is for this piece. I would still be unlikely to use the phrase "full score" for this, though, since the phrase is so connected to larger orchestral pieces.

Comment: Where would you draw the line between "full score" and "not full score"? How many instruments? This gets opinion-based very quickly. I think OP should ask for clarification if the purpose of the categorization isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

Given there are only two choices available:

1. *Full Score*: For a piece that includes two or more individual instruments, all parts are shown on a single system.
2. *Not Full Score*: A single or solo instrumental part, or an incomplete set of instrumental parts, are shown.

Solo instrumental parts in which that instrument is the only one involved in the piece, including piano scores, are not considered full score. A duet would be considered to be in full score if the parts are printed together in one system, but it would not be in full score if the parts are printed individually on facing pages.

Comment: The OP only mentions piano scores, but a more specific definition should also consider the case of percussions, which often have scores intended for a single musician playing multiple instruments ("drum set", but not always the *common* drum set).

Answer (score 0):

As written in some comments, it depends on how the categorization should work. Such differences are quite approximate in "analog" approaches, and mostly depend on context, while digital indexing requires more strict differentiation, even if sometimes it doesn't make a lot of sense.

If you're looking for a general approach that would allow a more comprehensive filtering (aka, showing all possible matches), a more appropriate and general solution would use logical subtraction: player/instrument count and complete score.

Following this principle, a standard two-staves piano piece would be considered as a full score just as much a piece for solo violin would.

Generally speaking, what [written by Aaron](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/133567/74331) is correct, but we should also consider that there are some exceptions: it's not just about the instrument count, but the player count too.

A typical case is for percussion: there are some pieces for solo percussion that *could* be played by one musician, or by many (each one playing one or more different instruments).

Another case is for two musicians playing the same instrument, such as "piano four hands" music.

What makes the difference is if the individual score makes sense as an *unique part*: would you ever publish/print a single staff of a standard two-staves piano part? I doubt it.

So, if the categorization is intended as a strict filtering, a standard part intended for piano solo cannot be considered as a full score.

If you aim for a broader filtering instead, any part of a piece written for a single instrument or player should be considered as a full score, no matter how many staves it has.